# How to pass every variable to every function on model Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have several variable on constructor. How do I pass them to another function ?
so I do not need to write them again .
Here my code :

```
class Validasi_model extends CI_Model {

    public $tabelmhs;

    public function __construct()
        {
        parent::__construct();

$tabelmaster = $this->input->post('tabelmaster');

$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM master_tabel where id_master_tabel = '$tabelmaster'");
$result = $query->result();

foreach ($result as $row){
    $tabelmhs = $row->nm_tabel_mahasiswa;
//i have lot variable here
}
}
```

I want to pass $tabelmhs to another function and so on

```
public function validasi_duplikat()
    {
$duplikat = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM $tabelmhs WHERE nipd IN (
 SELECT nipd FROM $datamhs GROUP BY nipd HAVING count(*) > 1) ");
 return $duplikat;
        }
```

Comment: where `validasi_duplikat()` located ?

Comment: in Validasi_model , right bellow construct

Comment: $this->yourfunction($tabelmhs) ?

Comment: @Mitch so I need to write it again in every function ?? I have lot of variable and lot of function, that's the problem. Is there any simple way ??

Comment: @BillyOrigin you can declare them outside constructor then you can access from anywhere in the class

Comment: I'm not sure @BillyOrigin because i never pass that many variables. However Fast Snail his answer might work :)

Comment: $Fast Snail it doesn't work, I got red mark error in my text editor (using DW) if I declare them outside any function ..

Comment: @BillyOrigin you have to add access modifier.like `public  $tabelmaster`.but you should still assign values in the constructor using `$this->tabelmaster=$this->input->post('tabelmaster');`